# subtracting times and dates in vba excel

Tags: excel, date, time, vba

I have a long sequence of times and dates, for example:

`4/10/2015  12:19:01 PM
4/10/2015  12:20:15 PM
...
4/10/2015  12:24:16 PM
4/10/2015  12:24:27 PM

And I would like to take the dates/times and convert the series into minutes, by subtracting the firt date/time and get the number of minutes elapsed.

so basically:

0 mins
76 mins
...
315 mins
326 mins

But I don't know how to do this in vba excel. I need to do this for multiple sheets, so I am trying to figure out how to write the code VBA so I can automate it.

Please help.

Comment: Assuming your dates and times are just standard Excel dates/times (i.e. a double precision number), and not strings, you can calculate minutes by just using (value - firstValue) * 24 * 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim time_diff As Integer

date1 = "4/10/2015 12:19:01 PM"
date2 = "4/10/2015 12:20:15 PM"
time_diff = (date2 - date1) * 24 * 60
MsgBox "time difference is " & time_diff & " minutes"
```

Comment: But does this mean that minutes is the default time measure in VBA?

Comment: if you want to find the difference in hours `time_diff = (date2 - date1) * 24` and for seconds `time_diff = (date2 - date1) * 24 * 60 * 60`

Comment: what is the default time measure in VBA? I'm trying to conceptualize where 24 * 60 comes from. And is this a universal rule in VBA? All times and dates are measured in this unit?

Comment: when you subtract two dates, you get the difference in days. To convert that to hours you multiple by 24 and to convert to minutes 24*60 and to seconds 24*60*60

Comment: Does excel measure dates a value? what is the date 01/00/00 valued as? And what is the value of date 9/3/2016?

Comment: 9/3/16 will be 42438. you can check it for yourself by converting a valid datetime value to number format